# Computer turns off a second after powering on

Tags: boot, power-supply, post

It doesn't even post. No beeps, flashing lights or anything. All the fans spin up for about a second and then it switches off again. I've tried disconnecting everything, so it's just a power supply + motherboard and resetting the BIOS. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was one of the fans inside the power supply that was a bit old and wasn't starting properly. I guess the power supply powers off if it detects one of the fans not spinning. I was able to give it a helping spin as I turned the PC on and everything worked. Maybe take care not to poke metal things into it to spin the fan though.